# Routing based on Async Authentication check using React-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

So have followed the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46162278/authenticate-async-with-react-router-v4) to do a router based on whether the user is authenticated or not.

My route looks like this (this is an Authentication only App)-

```
"/" -> Login
 |
 |
 |- "/home" -> User Home page based on some criteria of the logged in user
 |
 |- "/catalog" -> Catalog page based on some criteria of the logged in user
```

In short, the `/home` and `/catalog` are protected routes and only authenticated users are allowed. All non authenticated users must be routed to root i.e. `"/"` which is the login page. The authentication check function is Async so I have my index.js and App.js something like this-

index.js

```
import PrivateRoute from './App';

<BrowserRouter>
  <div>
    <Switch>
      <PrivateRoute path="/home" component={Client}/>
      <PrivateRoute path="/catalog" component={Catalog}/>
      <PrivateRoute path="/" component={Landing}/>
    </Switch>
  </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

App.js

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    loading: true,
    isAuthenticated: false,
    role: ''
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    getUserSession((isValid,session,err) => {
      if (isValid){
        console.log('is Valid Session');
        this.setState({
          loading: false,
          isAuthenticated: isValid,
        });
      }else if (err){
        console.log('is InValid Session');
        this.setState({
          loading: false,
        });
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { component: Component, ...rest } = this.props
    console.log(this.props);
    return (
      <Route
        {...rest}
        render={props =>
          this.state.isAuthenticated ? (
            <Component {...props} />
          ) : (
              this.state.loading ? (
                <div>LOADING</div>
              ) : (
                  <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/', state: { from: this.props.location } }} />
                )
            )
        }
      />
    )
  }
}
```

It's worth noting that I am not using Redux for grabbing the Authentication state of the user, instead using AWS Amplify method calls to simply get the user session. The `getUserSession` function returns whether a user session is Valid and some additional information like the session object etc.

I have 2 issues -

1. When an un-authenticated user comes in, the redirect is causing an infinite loop since `"/"` goes through the authentication check again and again via the `Redirect` causing an `Maximum update depth exceeded` error because of `setState` call in App.js.
2. If a user is authenticated then they end up in the `<Component {...props} />` line in App.js. This is ok as long as the user is hitting the specific `/home` or `/catalog` routes. However, if the user is authenticated and hits the root route `/` i would want them to re-direct them to one of either `/home` or `/catlog` routes and I am simply not getting how to do that.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: route `/` shouldn't be a private route.. there has to be a global route that doesn't check auth. login for instance wouldn't be a private route either. the other issue you have, you should check the path on will mount and push a new route if its `/`

Comment: Hi, yes, I moved to the `willMount` method with `/` is a public route and the other routes as protected using HOC that checks user authentication session. Thanks